# Home partition under /mount instead of /home

Tags: 20.04

I created two partitions:
30gb -> root
30gb -> home

I choose the option `something else` and assigned the two partitions and then started the install.

Now that its done installing, I have an SSD in my task bar that is the 30gb home partition.
It seems to be under `/mount` and I thought it would be under `/home`.

Why is it not part of the main storage? Can it be added to the root partition so I don't have to go through `/mount` to access the storage?

Comment: When using Something Else, you have to choose / (root) and /home so it is part of the install & added to fstab. If you did not you can follow this. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving But if only allocating 60GB having just / (root) is ok, also. Its when you have a large /home that you may want it separate. Or smaller /  and large data partition for the data that is normally in /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: I'll give the first link a go. Since having 60gb /root is okay, is there a way to add to /home to the existing /root partition without reformatting them both? From some searching it seems like it isn't possible

Comment: You cannot merge partitions. And should have good backups anyway. But if no data in your /home that you planned, you can just delete it, and expand / to be 60GB.

Comment: Alright, so I can just expand it. Thats what I'll do thanks!